# Lie Algebra in Particle Physics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, lie-algebra, group-representations

In his book " Lie Algebra in Particle Physics" Georgie directly put the relation $$(1-P)D(g)(1-P)=D(g)(1-P)...(1)$$
This came from the two previous relations: 
$$PD(g)P=D(g)P$$
$$PD(g)P=PD(g).$$
where $P$ is the projector and $D(g)$ is a representation.
How did he conclude relation (1)?

Comment: Just expand (1) and you see it. PS- Georgi is one of the worst books I have ever read. I recommend A. Zee’s book.

Comment: Thank you! I am yet to finish reading it. A. Zee's book is next on my list.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelAngelo about Georgi's book, though I must admit I wasn't a huge fan of Zee's book either.. Come to think of it, I'm not even sure how I ever learned group theory..